# Pandas : date as year, month ... in separated columns to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, multiple-columns

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this one :

```
        Y   M   D   h   m    s  A             B             C
0    2017  10  17   0   0  0.0  2 -1.921937e-05  7.803138e-12
1    2017  10  17   0   0  0.0  2 -9.109295e-09  1.261762e-11
2    2017  10  17   0   0  0.0  2 -7.391985e-09  1.145216e-11
3    2017  10  17   0   0  0.0  2 -2.785207e-08  7.311125e-12
```

i.e. where year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds are as integer or float in separated columns.

I'd like to know the better/faster way to get a Serie containing the date as datetime ?

Comment: have you tried the [`datetime64[ns]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Manually concatenating columns.

```
i = df.iloc[:, :6].astype(str)     
j = ['Y'] + '-' + i['M'] + '-' + i['D'] + ' ' + i['h'] + ':' + i['m'] + ':' + i['s'] 
pd.to_datetime(j)

0   2017-10-17
1   2017-10-17
2   2017-10-17
3   2017-10-17
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

**Option 2**
Have to credit piR for this. This involves smartly renaming your columns and passing a dataframe slice to `pd.to_datetime`.

```
m = dict(Y='year', M='month', D='day', h='hour', m='minute', s='second')
v = df.iloc[:, :6].rename(columns=m)

   year  month  day  hour  minute  second
0  2017     10   17     0       0     0.0
1  2017     10   17     0       0     0.0
2  2017     10   17     0       0     0.0
3  2017     10   17     0       0     0.0


pd.to_datetime(v)

0   2017-10-17
1   2017-10-17
2   2017-10-17
3   2017-10-17
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The option 2, with a column renaming looks the best